# The posts on my wordpress custom theme page display in different order

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, loops

I'm developing a wordpress theme and I have a little problem on the posts display, the theme is developed in bootstrap so I have a class col-md-6 (2 columns of 3) for the posts, and col-md-4 for the sidebar, in some pages the posts display perfectly right, but in other pages are with some white gaps. I thought it was cuz of the images, excerpt or title, but I tried took em off but also show the white gaps in some pages. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
    <div class="c-content-box c-size-md" >
            <div class="container hidden-phone">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="c-content-blog-post-card-1-grid col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-8"> 

                                    <?php

                                         if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="c-content-blog-post-card-1 c-option-2 c-bordered wow animate fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                                                <div class="c-media img">
                                                    <div class="c-overlay-wrapper">
                                                        <div class="c-overlay-content">
                                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail( '', array( 'style' => 'width:100%;height:auto' ) ); ?>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="c-body">
                                                    <div class="c-title c-font-bold c-font-uppercase" >
                                                        <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="c-author">
                                                        <span class="c-font-uppercase"><?php the_time( 'M j Y' ); ?></span>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="c-comments" style="text-align:center;">
                                                            <i class="icon-speech"></i> <?php comments_popup_link( '0 Comentarios', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios' ); ?>   
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <?php the_excerpt();  ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>                  
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endwhile;

                                    ?>

                                    <?php
                                    // Previous/next page navigation.
                                    the_posts_pagination( array(
                                        'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'goc' ),
                                        'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'goc' ),
                                        'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'goc' ) . ' </span>',
                                    ) );
                                    ?>  

                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 ">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 wow animate fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="1s">
                                        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

    <?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php

get_footer();
```

Comment: How do you margins work on this grid, do you have a margin-right only or does it apply to both sides? Have you tried using the :nth-child operator to drop the margin on the 2nd post? Only other thing I can think of is that third post is going to the right because you're floating left, and thats forcing it into an available space. Display flex will fix it

Answer (score 1):

That's because the boxes are floated and have slightly different heights, which (in your image) causes the third box to slip under the second one because there is still a tiny bit of vertical space enxt to the first one.

You can avoid this by using a fixed height for all boxes, or using `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap;` on the container element.

Comment: Hello  @Johannes ! I tried the fixed height and only works with px and it looks great on desktop but in mobile the boxes look huge and I dont like. The display flez and flex-wrap didnt work. do you have another solution? thanks

Comment: Well, on mobile probably the boxes are all above each other, so the height doesn't matter and you can reset the height to `auto` in a media query.

Comment: Perfect @Johannes !!! thanks ! I was so desperate that I forgot the media queries ! now it looks great!

Answer (score 1):

What version of Bootstrap are you using ?

You could avoid these unwanted wrapping behavior by adding some flex functionality, included in the 4th version of Bootstrap: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/

Alternatively, and if you're using Bootstrap 3, you could correct your issue by wrapping each 2 columns inside a `<div class="row"></div>` container.

It will be something like that:

```
<div class="row">
<?php
$colCount = 0;
while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
$colCount++;
        if ( have_posts() ): 
            if ($colCount % 2 == 0): ?>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!--The content of your column-->
        <?php endif;
endwhile;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @jminguely ! Thanks for your answer, this one look like the best option to fix the problem but I got lost trying to apply, my web crashed down, looks like there is a div that doesnt close, if you can help me a little bit to appply your answer into my code (the one that is on my question) :) King regards,

Comment: Well, I've maybe been a bit quick with my answer. I've corrected a typo & the logic should be better now. 
I hope it works better for you ?